# Unable to resolve class org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi in grails-oauth-scribe for grails 3

Tags: java, facebook, grails, groovy, oauth

This is probably a rookie mistake but I can't seem to find it, been trying for 2 days.
I'm trying to integrate a simple facebook login in my grails 3 app using the grails-oauth-scribe plugin which utilizes the Scribe oauth API. So it is natural that installing the plugin will install these dependency API classes. But I think it does'nt because when I import the FacebookAPI in my **application.groovy**

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi

oauth {
    providers {
        facebook {
            api = FacebookApi
            key = 'my key'
            secret = 'my secret'
            successUri = "${application.baseUrl}/hello/oauthFb"
            callback = "${application.baseUrl}/oauth/facebook/callback"
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
    $ grails compile --stacktrace --verbose                                              [21:54:04]
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: startup failed:
script1489599921993319590921.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
   ^

1 error

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script1489599921993319590921.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:946)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:542)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:211)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:221)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$parseClass.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:170)
    at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.loadGroovy(CodeGenConfig.groovy:148)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.loadApplicationConfig(GrailsCli.groovy:592)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:291)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:269)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: startup failed:
script1489599921993319590921.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
   ^

1 error
```

**build.gradle dependencies part**

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.1.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.1.Final"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:oauth:3.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    provided "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.1"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

I understand that it is a class resolution error so i have tried to include the scribe jar manually but nothing happens. I will post the **application.yml** if it helps

```
oauth:
    providers:
        facebook:
            api: org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
            key: 'my key'
            secret: 'secret'
```

everything seems alright to me, must be something silly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency:

```
    dependency {
        compile 'org.scribe:scribe:+'
    }
```